# Keras concatenated layers performing worse than individual CNNs

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm relatively new to keras/CNNs. I've built a model that concatenates the output from 3 sequential CNNs with some other metadata into a final Dense network. The outputs from the 3 individual layers are sensible and perform ok, but the final output when concatenated with the meta data is showing worse performance and doesn't seem to learn - even though some of this meta data should be very useful for prediction. The labels are one-hot coded classification data (4 different labels). I'm a bit confused why the final concatenated model is performing so poorly compared to the individual pieces, would appreciate any insight into what I might be doing wrong here.  Thanks!

```
# create first conv layers
first_input = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='int32', name='first_input')
x = Embedding(input_dim=num_features,output_dim=embedding_dim,input_length=input_shape[0])(first_input)
#x = Dropout(rate = dropout_rate)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)

x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)

aux_predictions = Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation)(x)

# now create a convolutional model for second
second_input = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='int32', name='second_input')
x = Embedding(input_dim=num_features,output_dim=embedding_dim,input_length=input_shape[0])(second_input)
#x = Dropout(rate = dropout_rate)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)

x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)

aux_predictions2 = Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation)(x)

# now create a convolutional model for second
third_input = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='int32', name='third_input')
x = Embedding(input_dim=num_features,output_dim=embedding_dim,input_length=input_shape[0])(third_input)
#x = Dropout(rate = dropout_rate)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)

x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=filters * 2,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                   strides = 1,
                                  activation='relu',
                                  bias_initializer='random_uniform',
                                  padding='same')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)

aux_predictions3 = Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation)(x)

# Now combine three CNN layers with metadata
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=metadata_dim, name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([aux_predictions, aux_predictions2, aux_predictions3, auxiliary_input ])
#x = Dropout(rate = dropout_rate)(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

model_output = Dense(op_units, activation=op_activation, name='model_output')(x)



opt = SGD(lr=0.01)

fullmetamodel = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input, third_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[aux_predictions, aux_predictions2, aux_predictions3, model_output])
fullmetamodel.compile(
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.], optimizer = opt)
callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2), TQDMNotebookCallback(leave_inner=False, leave_outer = True)] 
fullmetamodel.fit(x=[first_x_train, second_x_train, third_x_train, training_meta], y=[training_labels,training_labels,training_labels, training_labels],
                  batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_data=([first_x_val, second_x_val, third_x_val, val_meta], [val_labels, val_labels, val_labels, val_labels])
                  , verbose = 0, callbacks = callbacks)  # starts training


# Output, three conv layers working ok, concatenated model performing poorly
Training
50% 20/40 [2:49:34<2:49:23, 508.20s/it]
Epoch 20
[loss: 8.002, dense_118_loss: 0.749, dense_119_loss: 0.769, dense_120_loss: 0.876, model_output_loss: 7.523, dense_118_categorical_accuracy: 0.686
  , dense_119_categorical_accuracy: 0.626, dense_120_categorical_accuracy: 0.620, model_output_categorical_accuracy: 0.532] : 66% 265184/400000 [05:13<02:40, 840.90it/s]
```

Comment: How much training data do you have? Bigger models tend to take longer to train.

Comment: I'm using 400k in training data (though I have more). The model stopped after 28 epochs b/c I'd set the callback patience to 2.

Comment: Looking at the intermediate outputs, the 3 CNN layers produce reasonable probabilities for each of the 4 categories, but the concatenated layer then just predicts [0,0,0,1] for everyone (the most common category).

Comment: That raises another question I'm unsure of about early stopping. I have selected 'val_loss' as the quantity to monitor, but my model has 4 outputs - how can I be sure it is monitoring the 'val_loss' for the full model and not one of the intermediate outputs?